# Sign JAR without JRE but with OpenSSL?

Tags: jar, openssl, sign, manifest.mf

Our system has Java and C parts. On the C side, we are signing certain data using command-line scripts calling OpenSSL commands. Now we want to sign some JARs too. We already have established PKI (what is important for this case - private keys are accessible) "on the C side" and we try to avoid duplicating/extending that to the Java side.

What would be an easy way to get the JAR signed for someone who does not want to have JRE (but has OpenSSL)? I.e. I want to create the correct `MANIFEST.MF`, `KEY.SF` and `KEY.?SA` for my JAR. Their format is not complicated and this seems to be doable with some scripting. Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering own question.

Format of `MANIFEST.MF` and `KEY.SF` is [documented by Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Manifest-Overview). Surprisingly, exact content of the signature `KEY.?SA` (where "KEY" is the keystore alias of the signing key) is not detailed in the ["Signature File" section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Signature_File).

This `KEY.RSA` (for RSA signatures) can be created by OpenSSL command-line tools in exactly the way `jarsigner` creates it. Example for RSA signature and SHA256 digest:

```
$ openssl smime -sign -noattr -in META-INF/TEST1.SF -outform der -out META-INF/TEST1.RSA -inkey privateKey.pem -signer cert.pem -md sha256
```

Similarly the signature can be produced with OpenSSL C API. Snap of C code (no error checking):

```
  /* PKCS7_PARTIAL flag is needed to be able to change the digest from the default value */
  PKCS7 *signed_data = PKCS7_sign(NULL, NULL, NULL, data,
    PKCS7_NOATTR | PKCS7_DETACHED | PKCS7_PARTIAL
  );

  digest = EVP_get_digestbyname("sha256");

  PKCS7_sign_add_signer(signed_data, signcert, pkey, digest, flags);

  PKCS7_final(signed_data, NULL, 0);
```

Signature created in this way is identical to what `jarsigner` would have produced.

Comment: By any chance, do you know how to compute "SHA-256-Digest-Manifest-Main-Attributes" in the *.SF file ? That is, what data in what order ? :-)  I need to sign a jar file w/o jarsigner because we'll use an HSM key.

Comment: @Jan Goyvaerts see the source code for "python-javatools" on Github. Alternatively, ask a question here :-)

Comment: Thanks ! I'll debug the code and see what data it uses. At first sight it's the complete line, but that doesn't work from bash. But at least I know where to start now. :-)

Comment: Right... Can not build the project and my Pythonese is a bit rusty... There *must* a specification somewhere about the order and content of the checksum ! :-)

Comment: SOLVED ! Debugging the Jarsigner class in the incredible Keystore Explorer project brought the mechanism to light.